# Showing chronology of jobs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to add some chronology to my 'jobs' so that when someone posts a job it lists conveniently under the date in which it was created and other posts will then go above it based on recency. An example of this can be seen on [Dribble Jobs](http://dribbble.com/jobs).

I am not really sure how to best approach this as it is something I haven't done before, any suggestions on how to achieve it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rails timestamps](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html), which will make this very, very easy. Just use the `created_at` timestamp for the jobs, and order by that (or perhaps the `id` field).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply this is great! Do you have an example of how the code would look though as I have only ever allowed rails to use the default and can't seem to find an example? Thanks

Comment: First, make sure your `Job` model has a `created_at` field in the database. If it does, Rails will set it automatically when a new job is created. If you need to create the field, do it in a migration. The type of the field for the migration is `:datetime`. Then you can add `order(:created_at).reverse_order` to get the ordering you're wanting, though doing the ordering by `:id` instead of `:created_at` may be faster in the long run.

Comment: And is this written into the job model or the job view page? Thanks for your help!

Comment: the query that does the ordering? I would put in the controller.